# The input does not save on the text file

Tags: java

It is for a school project. I want to create a text file with JAVA.

Below is a part of a code that I want to use in a game.

- the user need to enter the name (only once); the code below keeps asking the names until cancelled.
- the name should be saved in a text file created in the beginning
- I tried to use array list but feel free to use any other data structures

This is what I have so far. I can enter the name but it is not saved in the txt file.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fileName = new FileWriter("MyFile.txt", true);


        ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
        String Player = " ";
        while (!Player.isEmpty()){
            Player = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name a friend please.");
           // if (!Player.isEmpty());

        }
    try{
       FileWriter fw;
        fw = new FileWriter(String.valueOf(fileName));
        Writer output = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        int sz = 1;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < sz ; i++){
           output.write(aList.get(i).toString() + "\n");
       }
        output.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I cannot create that file");
    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: I am sorry got the wrong code.

Comment: Warning; `import java.io.FileWriter;` unused import (you already imported `java.io.*`)

Comment: `sz` is always one, so your loop only runs once

Comment: Also `while (!Player.isEmpty())` will only loop if `Player` is *not* empty, which almost certainly not what you want

Comment: `FileWriter fileName = new FileWriter("MyFile.txt", true);` ← I’m not sure what you think that does, but it does not create a file name.  It opens a new Writer for that file.  Later, you call `String.valueOf(fileName)`, but fileName is a Writer, not a name, so the String value is going to be something useless.

Comment: You may use try-with-ressources in order to close the output. (It wouldn't be closed if any Exceptions occur). If you don't want to, you could do it in a finally block too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *File* to create a file, but that just simply creates a file. To write to a file, you could use *PrintWriter* . Below is the code:

```
import java.io.File; // importing File class
import java.io.PrintWriter; // importing PrintWriter class


public class TextFileWritingExample2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    java.util.Scanner sc=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    // creating a .txt file
    File createFile=new File("myFile.txt");
    // writing to the file created above
    PrintWriter writeFile=new PrintWriter(createFile);

    // asking for 4 names, you could change it in anyway you want
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        writeFile.println(name);
    }

     //**DO NOT FORGET TO CLOSE YOU WRITER** 
    writeFile.close();

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is kinda what I am looking for but I want to implement the JOptionpan to pop up a dialog box asking for "Enter name" and saved into the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try FileOutputStream to write to your file, as shown:

```
try{
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(createFile, true);
out.writeUTF(name.getBytes());
}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
```